# Strange Date Parsing Results

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to make a small helper app to assist in reading SCCM logs. Parsing the dates has been pretty straightforward until I get to the timezone offset. It is usually in the form of "+???". literal example: "11-01-2016 11:44:25.630+480"

DateTime.parse() handles this well most of the time. But occasionally I run into a time stamp that throws an exception. I cannot figure out why. This is where I need help. See example code below:

```
Dim dateA As DateTime = Nothing
Dim dateB As DateTime = Nothing
Dim dateStr_A As String = "11-07-2016 16:43:51.541+600"
Dim dateStr_B As String = "11-01-2016 11:44:25.630+480"

dateA = DateTime.Parse(dateStr_A)
dateB = DateTime.Parse(dateStr_B)

MsgBox(dateA.ToString & vbCrLf & dateB.ToString)
```

IF run it would seem dateStr_B is an invalid time stamp? Why is this? I've tried to figure out how to handle the +480 using the 'zzz' using .ParseExact() format as shown here [Date Formatting MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Am I missing something with the timezone offset? I've searched high and low but these SCCM logs seem to use a non standard way of representing the offset. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that +480 is indeed an invalid offset. The format of the offset from UTC (as produced when using the ["zzz" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#zzzSpecifier)) is hours and minutes. +600 is 6 hours and 0 minutes ahead of UTC, which is valid. +480 would be 4 hours and 80 minutes ahead of UTC, which is invalid as the number of minutes can't be more than 59.

If you have some external source of date and time strings that uses an offset that is simply a number of minutes (i.e. +600 means 10 hours and +480 means 8 hours), you will need to adjust the offset before using `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`.

[Edit]
The following function takes a timestamp with a positive or negative offset (of any number of digits) in minutes, and returns a DateTime. It throws an ArgumentException if the timestamp is not in a valid format.

```
Public Function DateTimeFromSCCM(ByVal ts As String) As DateTime
    Dim pos As Integer = ts.LastIndexOfAny({"+"c, "-"c})
    If pos < 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Timestamp must contain a timezone offset", "ts")

    Dim offset As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(ts.Substring(pos + 1), offset) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Timezone offset is not numeric", "ts")
    End If

    Dim hours As Integer = offset \ 60
    Dim minutes As Integer = offset Mod 60

    Dim timestamp As String = ts.Substring(0, pos + 1) & hours.ToString & minutes.ToString("00")
    Dim result As DateTime
    If Not DateTime.TryParse(timestamp, result) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid timestamp", "ts")
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I have added my tentative solution based off your suggestion.

Comment: Post Edit: Very cool. I'm definitely learning a lot here. I appreciate you taking the time to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the insight. I had a feeling I would need to handle this manually. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simple in the process. My knowledge of the date and time formatting is a bit lacking.

As such, I have altered my code so that it handles the offset. Granted I will have to add some more input validation in the final product.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dateA As DateTime = Nothing
        Dim dateB As DateTime = Nothing
        Dim dateStr_A As String = correctOffset("11-07-2016 16:43:51.541+600")
        Dim dateStr_B As String = correctOffset("11-07-2016 16:43:51.541+480")

        dateA = DateTime.Parse(dateStr_A)
        dateB = DateTime.Parse(dateStr_B)

        MsgBox(dateA.ToString & vbCrLf & dateB.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Function correctOffset(ByVal ts As String)
        Dim offset As Integer = CInt(ts.Substring(ts.Length - 3))
        Dim offHour As Integer = offset / 60
        Dim offMin As Integer = offset - (offHour * 60)

        Dim strhour As String = Nothing
        Dim strmin As String = Nothing

        If offHour <= 9 Then
            strhour = "0" & CStr(offHour)
        Else
            strhour = CStr(offHour)
        End If

        If offMin <= 9 Then
            strmin = "0" & CStr(offMin)
        Else
            strmin = CStr(offMin)
        End If

        Return ts.Substring(0, ts.Length - 3) & strhour & ":" & strmin
    End Function
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format of an SCCM timestamp (which is why I didn't attempt to code the offset correction in my answer). The code you posted appears to work with the two examples in your question, but do you needs to handle other cases? Can the offset be negative instead of positive? Is the offset always three characters or might it be two or four characters?

Comment: I suggest a few changes to ensure the code will compile with `Option Strict On`. (1) include an `As` clause in the correctOffset Function: `Public Function correctOffset(ByVal ts As String) As String`. (2) Use the integer divide operator (`\`) when dividing by 60 to indicate that the result is an integer: `Dim offHour As Integer = offset \ 60`.

Comment: I will have to check some of my server logs and see how cases with less or more than 3 digits are handled. I personally have not seen any, but that may be because I was not looking for those cases at the time. If it indeed uses negative offsets I high doubt I will ever see greater than 4 digits as 12 hours is 720 minutes and it would be strange to exceed a 12 hour offset if you can go forwards and backwards in a 24 hour period.


Thanks for the tip on using the ( ` ). I did not know that was a thing.

I will definitely create a stringent input validation check for the production build.

Comment: Looks like I may have mistyped. The integer divide operator is the backslash "\". I agree that four digit offsets should be unnecessary as long as there can be negative offsets (and I suspect there can be). I'll update my answer to show how I would code the `correctOffset` function to handle offsets that may not be three digits.

Comment: To satisfy any lingering questions. This is a time stamp from one of my servers in Spain. ( 11-15-2016 20:25:50.944-60 ) So, Negatives are possible and timezone offset is not 0 prefixed.